# Mongo date query fails on edge cases

Tags: mongodb

I'm puzzled by the lack of accuracy for date ranges around edge cases. I have documents whose dates always start at the very beginning of a day - hr/min/sec of 00:00:00 - and am unable to query them using the $gte operator.

```
> db.days.find({dateR : {$gte:new Date(2013,9,14)}},{dateR:1})
null

> db.days.find({dateR : {$gte:new Date(2013,9,13)}},{dateR:1})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("525b79b5c598c6f439000600"), "dateR" : ISODate("2013-10-14T00:00:00Z") }
```

Why doesn't the document found in the second query appear for the first query?

Comment: When I test in my machine, it works. would you add full code include data insertion?

Comment: Something is fishy about the first response. If mongodb doesn't find anything, it doesn't say `null` on the console, at least not any of the versions I have installed here. Also, like @EveryEvery, I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: I inserted the null for clarity, but it clearly worked against me. :) @johnnyHK is correct. This was a timezone issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because `new Date(2013,9,14)` creates the date in terms of the local time zone, but MongoDB dates are always UTC.

This should work:

```js
db.days.find({dateR: {$gte: new Date(Date.UTC(2013, 9, 14))}}, {dateR: 1})
```